# How to validate XML with RELAXNG?

Tags: php, xml, validation, relaxng

Why is [this XML](https://github.com/admonkey/validate-relaxng/blob/ebab1e7358e4343b4aeb6ff19ab6d12bc52b4bbf/valid.xml#L9) still valid when [changing the integer](https://github.com/admonkey/validate-relaxng/blob/ebab1e7358e4343b4aeb6ff19ab6d12bc52b4bbf/invalid.xml#L9) from `id="33426841601"` to `id="asdf"` ?

I'm totally new to RELAXNG, but I expect [this part of the vendor-provided schema](https://github.com/admonkey/validate-relaxng/blob/ebab1e7358e4343b4aeb6ff19ab6d12bc52b4bbf/relaxng.xml#L88) to invalidate it:

```
<r:attribute name="id">
      <r:data type="integer"/>
</r:attribute>
```

But no matter how I tamper with the XML, [`DOMDocument::relaxNGValidate`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.relaxngvalidate.php) always returns true.

```
<?php
$valid = new DOMDocument;
$valid->load('valid.xml');
var_dump($valid->relaxNGValidate('relaxng.xml'));

$invalid = new DOMDocument;
$invalid->load('invalid.xml');
var_dump($invalid->relaxNGValidate('relaxng.xml'));
```

---

For this question, I have prepared a repository of these files for [download on Github](https://github.com/admonkey/validate-relaxng) so that line numbers can be easily referenced. It's a scrubbed sample provided by the company [Digital Measures](https://www.digitalmeasures.com/). In case that link is broken, here are the files:

## valid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2016-06-13">
    <Record userId="123456" username="jeffp" termId="129" dmd:surveyId="1234567">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="AACSBSUFF" entryKey="Participating" text="Participating"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="WCBD" text="WCBD"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="QUALIFICATION" entryKey="Instructional Practitioner" text="Instructional Practitioner"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="RANK" entryKey="Academic Staff" text="Academic Staff"/>
        <GENSERVE id="33426841601" dmd:lastModified="2011-03-15T10:23:01" dmd:startDate="2010-07-01">
            <TYPE>University</TYPE>
            <TYPEOTHER/>
            <ORG>University Academic Advising Council   </ORG>
            <ROLE>Committee Member</ROLE>
            <ROLEOTHER/>
            <OFFICE>President/Elect/Past</OFFICE>
            <RESPONSIBILITIES/>
            <NUMHOURS/>
            <ELECAPP>Elected</ELECAPP>
            <AUDIENCE>Local</AUDIENCE>
            <EXOFFICIO/>
            <DTM_START>July</DTM_START>
            <DTD_START/>
            <DTY_START>2010</DTY_START>
            <START_START>2010-07-01</START_START>
            <START_END>2010-07-31</START_END>
            <DTM_END/>
            <DTD_END/>
            <DTY_END/>
            <END_START></END_START>
            <END_END></END_END>
        </GENSERVE>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

## invalid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2016-06-13">
    <Record userId="123456" username="jeffp" termId="129" dmd:surveyId="1234567">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="AACSBSUFF" entryKey="Participating" text="Participating"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="DEPARTMENT" entryKey="WCBD" text="WCBD"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="QUALIFICATION" entryKey="Instructional Practitioner" text="Instructional Practitioner"/>
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="RANK" entryKey="Academic Staff" text="Academic Staff"/>
        <GENSERVE id="asdf" dmd:lastModified="2011-03-15T10:23:01" dmd:startDate="2010-07-01">
            <TYPE>University</TYPE>
            <TYPEOTHER/>
            <ORG>University Academic Advising Council   </ORG>
            <ROLE>Committee Member</ROLE>
            <ROLEOTHER/>
            <OFFICE>President/Elect/Past</OFFICE>
            <RESPONSIBILITIES/>
            <NUMHOURS/>
            <ELECAPP>Elected</ELECAPP>
            <AUDIENCE>Local</AUDIENCE>
            <EXOFFICIO/>
            <DTM_START>July</DTM_START>
            <DTD_START/>
            <DTY_START>2010</DTY_START>
            <START_START>2010-07-01</START_START>
            <START_END>2010-07-31</START_END>
            <DTM_END/>
            <DTD_END/>
            <DTY_END/>
            <END_START></END_START>
            <END_END></END_END>
        </GENSERVE>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

## relaxng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<r:grammar xmlns:r="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" xmlns:dms="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/schema-metadata" datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
    <r:start>
        <r:choice>
            <r:element name="Data">
                <r:ref name="Data"/>
            </r:element>
            <r:element name="Data" ns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data">
                <r:ref name="Data"/>
            </r:element>
        </r:choice>
    </r:start>
    <r:define name="Data">
        <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
        <r:ref name="otherElements"/>
        <r:zeroOrMore>
            <r:ref name="Record-INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-Business"/>
        </r:zeroOrMore>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="otherAttributes">
        <r:zeroOrMore>
            <r:attribute>
                <r:anyName>
                    <r:except>
                        <r:nsName/>
                    </r:except>
                </r:anyName>
            </r:attribute>
        </r:zeroOrMore>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="otherElements">
        <r:zeroOrMore>
            <r:element>
                <r:anyName>
                    <r:except>
                        <r:nsName/>
                    </r:except>
                </r:anyName>
                <r:zeroOrMore>
                    <r:choice>
                        <r:attribute>
                            <r:anyName/>
                        </r:attribute>
                        <r:text/>
                        <r:ref name="anyElements"/>
                    </r:choice>
                </r:zeroOrMore>
            </r:element>
        </r:zeroOrMore>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="anyElements">
        <r:element>
            <r:anyName/>
            <r:zeroOrMore>
                <r:choice>
                    <r:attribute>
                        <r:anyName/>
                    </r:attribute>
                    <r:text/>
                    <r:ref name="anyElements"/>
                </r:choice>
            </r:zeroOrMore>
        </r:element>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Record-INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-Business">
        <r:element name="Record">
            <r:oneOrMore>
                <r:choice>
                    <r:attribute name="userId">
                        <r:data type="integer"/>
                    </r:attribute>
                    <r:attribute name="username">
                        <r:data type="string"/>
                    </r:attribute>
                    <r:attribute name="UniversityID">
                        <r:data type="string"/>
                    </r:attribute>
                </r:choice>
            </r:oneOrMore>
            <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
            <r:interleave>
                <r:ref name="otherElements"/>
                <r:zeroOrMore>
                    <r:element name="GENSERVE" dms:text="General Service">
                        <r:optional>
                            <r:attribute name="id">
                                <r:data type="integer"/>
                            </r:attribute>
                        </r:optional>
                        <r:ref name="Access"/>
                        <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                        <r:interleave>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="TYPE" dms:text="Service Type">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-ServiceType"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="TYPEOTHER" dms:text="Explanation of &quot;Other&quot;">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="string-maxLength-20000"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="ORG" dms:text="Organization/Committee/Club">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="string-maxLength-20000"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="ROLE" dms:text="Position/Role">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-ServicePosition"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="ROLEOTHER" dms:text="Explanation of &quot;Other&quot;">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="string-maxLength-20000"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="OFFICE" dms:text="Title/Office Held">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-OfficeType"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="RESPONSIBILITIES" dms:text="Describe the significance of the position and your responsibilities">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="string-maxLength-20000"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="NUMHOURS" dms:text="Approx. Number of Hours Spent Per Year">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="double"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="ELECAPP" dms:text="Elected/Appointed?">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-AppointedElected"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="AUDIENCE" dms:text="Audience">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-ServiceAudience"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="EXOFFICIO" dms:text="Served Ex-Officio?">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-YesNo"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="DTM_START" dms:text="Start Month">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-Month"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="DTD_START" dms:text="Start Day">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="integer-minInclusive-1-maxInclusive-31"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="DTY_START" dms:text="Start Year">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="integer-minInclusive-1900-maxInclusive-2100"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="START_START" dms:text="Start Start">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="date"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="START_END" dms:text="Start End">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="date"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="DTM_END" dms:text="End Month">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="Option-Month"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="DTD_END" dms:text="End Day">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="integer-minInclusive-1-maxInclusive-31"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="DTY_END" dms:text="End Year">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="integer-minInclusive-1900-maxInclusive-2100"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="END_START" dms:text="End Start">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="date"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="END_END" dms:text="End End">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:ref name="date"/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                            <r:optional>
                                <r:element name="UPLOAD_FILE" dms:text="Supporting Documents">
                                    <r:ref name="Access"/>
                                    <r:ref name="otherAttributes"/>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:attribute name="newFile">
                                            <r:data type="string"/>
                                        </r:attribute>
                                    </r:optional>
                                    <r:optional>
                                        <r:text/>
                                    </r:optional>
                                </r:element>
                            </r:optional>
                        </r:interleave>
                    </r:element>
                </r:zeroOrMore>
            </r:interleave>
        </r:element>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Access">
        <r:optional>
            <r:attribute name="access">
                <r:choice>
                    <r:value>READ_ONLY</r:value>
                    <r:value>HIDDEN</r:value>
                    <r:value>LOCKED</r:value>
                </r:choice>
            </r:attribute>
        </r:optional>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Option-ServiceType">
        <r:choice>
            <r:value>College</r:value>
            <r:value>Department</r:value>
            <r:value>Professional</r:value>
            <r:value>Public/Community</r:value>
            <r:value>Student Organization</r:value>
            <r:value>University</r:value>
            <r:value>Other</r:value>
        </r:choice>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="string-maxLength-20000">
        <r:data type="string">
            <r:param name="maxLength">20000</r:param>
        </r:data>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Option-ServicePosition">
        <r:choice>
            <r:value>Activity to Bridge Campus and Community</r:value>
            <r:value>Administrative Assignment, Assistant Dean</r:value>
            <r:value>Administrative Assignment, Associate Dean</r:value>
            <r:value>Administrative Assignment, Dean</r:value>
            <r:value>Administrative Assignment, Other</r:value>
            <r:value>Attendee, Award Ceremony</r:value>
            <r:value>Attendee, Convocation</r:value>
            <r:value>Attendee, Graduation</r:value>
            <r:value>Attendee, Meeting</r:value>
            <r:value>Attendee, Orientation</r:value>
            <r:value>Co-Chair</r:value>
            <r:value>Committee Chair</r:value>
            <r:value>Committee Member</r:value>
            <r:value>Conference Chairperson</r:value>
            <r:value>Conference Discussant</r:value>
            <r:value>Conference Panel</r:value>
            <r:value>Conference Program Organizer</r:value>
            <r:value>Conference Reviewer</r:value>
            <r:value>Conference Session Chair</r:value>
            <r:value>Conference Track Organizer</r:value>
            <r:value>Department Chairperson</r:value>
            <r:value>Endowed Chair Review Committee</r:value>
            <r:value>External Grant Proposal Reviewer</r:value>
            <r:value>Guest Speaker</r:value>
            <r:value>Interaction with Industry</r:value>
            <r:value>Internal Grant Proposal Reviewer</r:value>
            <r:value>Member of Professional Organization</r:value>
            <r:value>Prepare/Grade Certification Exams</r:value>
            <r:value>Pro Bono Professional Service</r:value>
            <r:value>Student Org Advisor (Non-Professional Org)</r:value>
            <r:value>Student Org Advisor (Professional Org)</r:value>
            <r:value>Student Placement</r:value>
            <r:value>Student Recruiter</r:value>
            <r:value>Tenure Reviewer for Another Institution</r:value>
            <r:value>Track Co-Chair</r:value>
            <r:value>University Senate Service</r:value>
            <r:value>Workshop Organizer</r:value>
            <r:value>Other</r:value>
        </r:choice>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Option-OfficeType">
        <r:choice>
            <r:value>Member</r:value>
            <r:value>President/Elect/Past</r:value>
            <r:value>Other Officer</r:value>
            <r:value>Other</r:value>
        </r:choice>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="double">
        <r:data type="double"/>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Option-AppointedElected">
        <r:choice>
            <r:value>Appointed</r:value>
            <r:value>Elected</r:value>
        </r:choice>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Option-ServiceAudience">
        <r:choice>
            <r:value>International</r:value>
            <r:value>National</r:value>
            <r:value>Regional</r:value>
            <r:value>State</r:value>
            <r:value>Local</r:value>
        </r:choice>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Option-YesNo">
        <r:choice>
            <r:value>Yes</r:value>
            <r:value>No</r:value>
        </r:choice>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="Option-Month">
        <r:choice>
            <r:value>January</r:value>
            <r:value>February</r:value>
            <r:value>March</r:value>
            <r:value>April</r:value>
            <r:value>May</r:value>
            <r:value>June</r:value>
            <r:value>July</r:value>
            <r:value>August</r:value>
            <r:value>September</r:value>
            <r:value>October</r:value>
            <r:value>November</r:value>
            <r:value>December</r:value>
        </r:choice>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="integer-minInclusive-1-maxInclusive-31">
        <r:data type="integer">
            <r:param name="minInclusive">1</r:param>
            <r:param name="maxInclusive">31</r:param>
        </r:data>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="integer-minInclusive-1900-maxInclusive-2100">
        <r:data type="integer">
            <r:param name="minInclusive">1900</r:param>
            <r:param name="maxInclusive">2100</r:param>
        </r:data>
    </r:define>
    <r:define name="date">
        <r:data type="date"/>
    </r:define>
</r:grammar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop `xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"` from the `Data` element.

The RelaxNG grammar you’re using defines two different `Data` elements: a `Data` element in no namespace, and another in the `http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data` namespace. Your doc seems to be an instance of what the grammar expects for the no-namespace case.

Drop the `xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data"` from the `Data` element in the `invalid.xml` file you should get something like the following errors:

> invalid.xml:4:82: error: Attribute “termId” not allowed on element “Record” in this context.
>   invalid.xml:9:95: error: Bad value “asdf” for attribute “id” on element “GENSERVE”.

Comment: If I drop it, then they are both invalid.

Comment: What are you using to validate? I'm not getting those specific error messages from DOMDocument or xmllint.

Comment: The `valid.xml` file is not valid because the grammar does not define a `termid` attribute for the `Record` element. It only defines the attributes `userId`, `username`, and `UniversityID` for the `Record` element.

Comment: I’m using `jing.jar` from the command line: `java -jar jing.jar schema.rng valid.xml`. I would not recommend trusting the RelaxNG checking in `xmllint`.

Comment: When dropping that namespace, DOMDocument and xmllint are both giving me errors: `Extra element GENSERVE in interleave` and `Element Data has extra content: Record`

Comment: Yeah I do not know why DOMDocument and xmllint and give those errors but I would guess it is because they are both relying on xmllib2 and there is some bug in xmllib2 that prevents it from evaluating the grammar correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120721/discussion-between-sideshowbarker-and-jeff-puckett-ii).